How can I iterate the columns in the same dataframe and get the pairs of range where the value lies?
I'm new in pandas. I want to check whether my Price values lies between P1 and P2 column values, if not then I could check between columns P2 and P3 and so on.
I don't know how can I do it within same dataframe.
Given is the data frame -
   Quantity  Price data1 data2   Q1     P1   Q2     P2    Q3      P3  ....
0       1.1  100.1     A     D  4.4  700.7  4.4  100.1  13.3  1300.3  ....
1       2.2  200.2     B     E  5.5  800.8  5.5  110.1  14.4  1400.4  ....
2       3.3  300.3     C     F  6.6  900.9  6.6  120.2  15.5  1500.5  ....

So far, I've tried breaking into two dataframes with df1 ['Quantity','Price'] and df2 ['Q1','P1',....]
and comparing like this
for row in df1.itertuples():
  for k in [1,i]: #where i has the last nth term of P
    if df1["Price"].between(df2[f"P{str(k)}"],df2[f"P{str(k+1)}]):  #Error in this line
       print("matched")
       

Showing ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
PS.
Edit for expected output - I've also changed value of Price in second row for different test case.
    Quantity  Price data1 data2   Q1     P1   Q2     P2    Q3      P3  ....  output1    output2
0       1.1  100.1     A     D   4.4  700.7  4.4  100.1  13.3  1300.3  ....  4.4,700.7  4.4,100.1   #output1-Q1,P1  output2-Q2,P2 as Price lies between P1&P2
1       2.2  900.2     B     E   5.5  800.8  5.5  810.1  14.4  1400.4  ....  5.5,810.1  14.4,1400.4 #output1-Q2,P2  output2-Q3,P3 as Price lies between P2&P3 here
2       3.3  300.3     C     F   6.6  900.9  6.6  120.2  15.5  1500.5  ....  6.6,900.9  6.6,120.2   #output1-Q1,P1  output2-Q2,P2 as Price lies between P1&P2


Thanks. Help will be appreciated.

What is the exact expected output?

Also, is 200.2 between 800.8 and 110.1?

@mozway The expected output is to get that particular both pairs of (Q, P) between which the Price lies. Because I've to perform further calculation on that. Yes, 200.2 lies in the range of 800.8 and 110.1

@mozway Hi, I've edited my question with expected output. thanks again.

Checking if Price is between(P1, P2), then between(P2, P3)... could be simplified to checking if Price is between the min P and max P.
You could use a vectorial approach:
tmp = df.filter(regex=r'P\d+')

df['match'] = df['Price'].between(tmp.min(axis=1), tmp.max(axis=1))

If you really need to explicitly test the successive pairs of columns (without changing the order), you could loop over the pairs with itertools.pairwise and aggregate with numpy.logical_or.reduce:
from itertools import pairwise

n = 3  # max P
df['match'] = np.logical_or.reduce([df['Price'].between(df[f'P{a}'], df[f'P{b}'])
                                    for a,b in pairwise(range(1, n+1))])

Output:
   Quantity  Price data1 data2   Q1     P1   Q2     P2    Q3      P3  match
0       1.1  100.1     A     D  4.4  700.7  4.4  100.1  13.3  1300.3   True
1       2.2  200.2     B     E  5.5  800.8  5.5  110.1  14.4  1400.4   True
2       3.3  300.3     C     F  6.6  900.9  6.6  120.2  15.5  1500.5   True


The expected output is to get that particular both pairs of (Q, P) between which the Price lies. Because I've to perform further calculation on that.

@Twinkle can you update your question with the explicit output (in the same format as your example input)

Hi, I've edited my question with expected output. thanks again.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Quantity': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
    'Price': [100.1, 900.2, 300.3],
    'data1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'data2': ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    'Q1': [4.4, 5.5, 6.6],
    'P1': [700.7, 800.8, 900.9],
    'Q2': [4.4, 5.5, 6.6],
    'P2': [100.2, 110.1, 120.2],
    'Q3': [13.3, 14.4, 15.5],
    'P3': [1300.3, 1400.4, 1500.5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pcols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('P')]
pvals = df[pcols].values

p_min = np.min(pvals,axis=1)
p_max = np.max(pvals,axis=1)

df['p_min'] = p_min
df['p_max'] = p_max

#if we want all these in 1 column
df['p_min_p_max'] = np.char.add(np.char.add(p_min.astype(str), ','), p_max.astype(str))
print(df[['p_min'   ,'p_max'   ,'p_min_p_max']])
   p_min   p_max   p_min_p_max
0  100.1  1300.3  100.1,1300.3
1  110.1  1400.4  110.1,1400.4
2  120.2  1500.5  120.2,1500.5

